# How to apply this patch file

Tags: git, git-patch

There is what looks to be a patch file in this post [here](https://github.com/c9/core/issues/241#issuecomment-284794640).  I've tried copying that text into a `changes.patch` file, `clone`ing the repo, `cd`ing into the cloned repo, and then doing a `git apply --check ../changes.patch`, but I just get:

```
error: patch failed: plugins/c9.vfs.standalone/standalone.js:110
error: plugins/c9.vfs.standalone/standalone.js: patch does not apply
```

Is the text in the above post actually suitable as a `.patch` file?  Any other way I can apply it (without resorting to the manual method... which wouldn't be too arduous in this case, but I'd like to know how to do it properly).

Comment: Adding `-3` or `--3way` tells your Git to construct a three-way merge if needed and possible. This uses the `index: ...` blob hashes, which works best if the diff was generated with `--full-index` (this one wasn't so will work only if `73fbdcc` uniquely identifies a blob in your repository). If the base is not present, the last method of applying is with `--reject`, which applies those parts that fit and leaves the rejections in `.rej` file for you to hand-apply.

Comment: Thanks @torek... I had to go with `--reject` because nothing else was working, and it applied maybe 6 hunks OK, with 1 rejected... saved some work... thanks!